# Custom Korean Font for Themify Ultra Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, fonts, wordpress-theming

I am using Themify Ultra to build my Wordpress site. Is it possible to customize Korean fonts? If so, can I do it using the Themify Builder or must I use the Wordpress back-end "Customize" option? I would really appreciate it if someone gave me a detailed process or directed me to a link describing the process. Thank you very much. : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try placing this on the head tags

@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/hanna.css);

/*and then use it on css:*/

font-family: 'Hanna', sans-serif;

just make sure you make those changes in your child theme, that why it wont affect the site when it updates.

Comment: If this was helpful to you. Can you please click on the check mark

Comment: Ooh so sorry for the late reply. I haven't been active on stackoverflow lately but am trying to change that! Thank you for your answer and patience : )